# casting from void** to int

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers

I have a dynamic 2D array stored in a `void**` pointer, and I am just wondering how I am supposed to cast/dereference the values so that they can be printed?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
/* Assume that I have a data structure called graph with some 
 * element "void** graph" in it and some element "int order" */

void foo(graph_t *graph)
{
    int **matrix;

    /*safe malloc works fine, it uses calloc to initialise it all to zeroes*/
    matrix = safe_malloc(graph->order * sizeof(int*)); 

    for (i = 0; i < graph->order; i++)
        matrix[i] = safe_malloc(graph->order * sizeof(int));

    /* storing matrix in the data structure */
    matrix = (int**)graph->graph;

    printf("%d\n", (int)graph->graph[2][2]);
}
```

When I try and compile it, the compiler gives me the warning: "dereferencing 'void *' pointer", and the error: "invalid use of void expression".

What should I do to cast the `void**` pointer so that I can print elements from `graph->graph`?

EDIT:

thanks for everyone's help; i cant make graph->graph of type int** because it needs to hold mulitple types of data, the only one i am having trouble with implementing is the int** array.

i changed matrix = (int**)graph->graph to graph->graph = (void**)matrix and that worked fine, i am able to print elements of the array, however now if i implement a separate function:

```
void print_foo(graph_t *graph)
{
    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < graph->order; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < graph->order; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", ((int**)graph->graph)[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

it just gives me a segmentation fault, however if i run that block of code in the original foo(graph_t *graph), it prints the 2D array fine.

can someone please explain what is happening to graph->graph so that it wont print if i call it from a different function

Comment: Note: You're leaking memory with this line: `matrix = (int**)graph->graph;`. You just assigned `matrix` the return of a `malloc()` call. Second, what is `graph_t`? It looks like it has a member (`graph`) that is a `void**` You can't dereference a `void*` (which is what your second index is doing). There is no "type" there, and thus no mechanism of knowing anything about it. There is no reason to have a void** for your "hidden" array. A `void*` will work, but you need to understand pointers more before that gels.

Comment: See also [Casting `void **` to 2D array of `int` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c).

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
typedef struct graph_t
{
    int order;
    void **graph;
} graph_t;
```

and assuming that you allocate `graph->graph` as an array of `int *` and a series of arrays of `int`, then you can, if you must, write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct graph_t
{
    int order;
    void **graph;
} graph_t;

extern void *safe_malloc(size_t n);
extern void foo(graph_t *graph);

void foo(graph_t *graph)
{
    int **matrix;

    /*safe malloc works fine, it uses calloc to initialise it all to zeroes*/
    matrix = safe_malloc(graph->order * sizeof(int*)); 

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->order; i++)
        matrix[i] = safe_malloc(graph->order * sizeof(int));

    /* storing matrix in the data structure */
    graph->graph = (void **)matrix; // Reverse order of assignment
    // C compiler complains without the cast - the cast is nasty!

    printf("%d\n", ((int **)graph->graph)[2][2]);
}
```

The code should check that `graph->order >= 3` to avoid overflow problems.

However, the structure is pretty nasty, and the necessary casting in the `printf()` statement is enough to make you realize why it is nasty.  You'd be far better off with an `int **graph;` in the structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct graph_t
{
    int order;
    int **graph;
} graph_t;

extern void *safe_malloc(size_t n);
extern void foo(graph_t *graph);

void foo(graph_t *graph)
{
    int **matrix;

    matrix = safe_malloc(graph->order * sizeof(int*)); 

    for (int i = 0; i < graph->order; i++)
        matrix[i] = safe_malloc(graph->order * sizeof(int));

    graph->graph = matrix;

    printf("%d\n", graph->graph[2][2]);
}
```

Both of these compile without warnings, even under stringent warning levels.  Neither has formally been tested by creating a `main()` function to exercise it.  You also need to have a function `bar(graph_t *graph)` to release the allocated memory, of course.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. i have to keep graph as a void** pointer so that i am able to store multiple types of data in that space. i have a follow-up question based your response, but i might just edit my original question so i can use code..