# Trying to store complex array into a class c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am not very good with c++ and was wondering why an error happens with arrays inside of arrays, but works fine with a normal array (and how to fix it possibly).

Heres the code (just trying to store an array inside a class upon constructing it):

```
class foo {
    int* stored;
public:
    foo(int* ptr) {
        stored = ptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    int arr[][2] = {{1,4},{5,7},{2,5}};
    foo obj(arr);
}
```

When the array is something like `int arr[] = {1,2,3}` it works without errors, but the normal code gives me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo::foo(int [3][2])'
```

I searched around for a while, but I don't really know what to search for in the first place, which is why I am asking here (but I feel it has something to do with pointers). Thanks for any help.

Comment: @texasbruce An array of arrays is **not** the same as a pointer to a pointer. See e.g. [this answer of mine to see why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to pass an array of arrays of integers as a single integer pointer, which will not work. While it's true that an array decay to pointer when passed, an array of arrays can not be a single pointer, and not a pointer to pointer either.

It can however be used as an pointer to array:

```
class foo
{
    int (*stored)[2];

public:
    foo(int (*ptr)[2]) : stored(ptr) {}
};
```

The parentheses in the declaration is needed because otherwise it would be an array of pointers.

However, I would recommend against using raw arrays, and move to [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which of course can be nested:

```
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> arr = {
    {{ 1, 2 }},
    {{ 3, 4 }}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look more into vectors and arrays from the std thing, I never really knew anything about them.

Comment: @lemondrop I've updated my answer with links to reference pages for the standard containers.

Comment: @lemondrop: There is `std::complex` as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How would you pass a vector thing like that to a class? Do they work the same way as normal arrays? Edit: Apparently you can just do `foo(vector<array<int,2>> ptr) : stored(ptr) {}`, so nevermind

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your code (even if it worked) would not store an array. In your class you have a *pointer* so all you are storing is a pointer to an array. It is important to get these distinctions clear in your head.

You have to declare a pointer that is compatible with the array you are trying to 'store'. That pointer is `int (*stored)[2]`, that is a pointer to an array of two ints.

Its actually pretty simple

```
int* is compatible with int[]
int (*)[N] is compatible with int[][N]
int (*)[N][M] is compatible with int[][N][M]
```

etc. etc. But the parentheses do confuse people. They are necessary because the `*` operator has a lower priority than the `[]` operator.