# what's the difference between char *s[] and char s[][20] in C?

Tags: c, string

Check this first code, If I write `char *tracks[]` instead of `char tracks[][80]`, it seems still working same perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = { "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
        "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town", "Dancing with a Dork",
        "From here to maternity", "The girl from Iwo Jima", };

void find_track(char search_for[]) {    //'char *search_for' is equivalent.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
            printf("Track %i(Line %i):'%s'\n", i, i + 1, tracks[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    scanf("%79s", search_for);  //fgets(search_for,80,stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

But check this second code, If I try to use `char juices[][20]` instead of `char *juices[]` , the compiler give error, I want to know why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse(char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *t = s + len - 1;
    while (t >= s) {
        printf("%c", *t);
        t = t - 1; //pointer arithmetic
    }
    puts("");
}

int main() {
    char *juices[] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", "uglifruit",
            "rumberry", "kiwifruit", "mulberry", "strawberry", "blueberry",
            "blackberry", "starfruit" };

    char *a;

    puts(juices[6]);
    print_reverse(juices[7]);
    a = juices[2];
    juices[2] = juices[8];
    juices[8] = a;
    puts(juices[8]);
    print_reverse(juices[(18 + 7) / 5]);

    puts(juices[2]);
    print_reverse(juices[9]);
    juices[1] = juices[3];
    puts(juices[10]);
    print_reverse(juices[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is quite strange, because if you check third code below, it will give error because pointer to a string literal can not be updated. If the thing is like this, then in second code `char *juices[]` is array of pointers to string literals, and then `juices[2]` is a pointer to `"sharonfruit"`, how can it be updated?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char *cards = "JQK";  //you should use char cards[]="JQK";
char a_card = cards[2];

cards[2] = cards[1];
cards[1] = cards[0];
cards[0] = cards[2];
cards[2] = cards[1];
cards[1] = a_card;

puts(cards);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: See e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558) to see the difference between an array of arrays and an array of pointers.

Comment: `juices[2] = juices[8];` : this cannot to array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char tracks[][80] = { "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town", "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity", "The girl from Iwo Jima", };
```

Creates an array of array of `char` or in other words, creates a two dimensional array of `char` and initializes each index with each strings. The  number of strings is determined by the compiler during compile-time and the maximum size of each string is 80.

```
char *tracks[] = { "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town", "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity", "The girl from Iwo Jima", };
```

declares an array of `char` pointers. Each pointer points to each string literal. The number of pointers is determined by the compiler during compile-time.

**String Literals are immutable** meaning that it cannot be changed.

In your first two programs using `tracks`, the first version(`char tracks[][80]`) and the second version(`char* tracks[]`) works as strings aren't changed and arrays are not *assigned*.

In the second two programs using `juices`, the first version works(`char* juices[]`) because pointers can be altered,i.e, the location where they point to can be changed, but the second version(`char juices[][80]`) doesn't because you *assign* arrays. Keep in mind that **Arrays are not *assignable***.

To fix the problem, you can use the `strcpy` function from the `string.h` library to interchange the strings stored in `char juices[][80]`.  Do note that memory needs to be allocated for variable `a` if you are going to attempt this.

Comment: Did you test the second program? If you use char[][80] it will fail, and if you use char* juices[] it work!

Comment: @LeeWilliam , On closer inspection of the second program, I found out that it does not modify the string literals. It interchanges them. Of course you can make a pointer point to some other address. But in case of `char[][80]`, you try to *assign* arrays. Arrays are not assignable. You must use `strcpy` to copy each string. Do note that memory needs to be allocated for `a` if you are going to do it. --- I'm editing my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the "outermost" array (ie. the first `[]`) are automatically type-converted to a pointer to the first element.

Thus,

```
char tracks[][80]
```

declares a pointer to a `char` array (of length 80).

However

```
char *tracks[]
```

obviously is an array of char-pointers, which is something different. The compiler knows that and won't let you do that.

Also, these things are something different in memory: the array-compound definitely is linear in memory, the array of pointers might contain pointers that point *anywhere* in memory.