# what is wrong with the function parameter?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class Type>
void Knapsack(Type *v,int *w,int c,int n,Type **m)
{
 int i,j;
    int jMax=max(w[n]-1,c);
    for(j=0;j<=jMax;j++)
    m[n][j]=0;
for(j=w[n];j<=c;j++)
    m[n][j]=v[n];
for(i=n-1;i>1;i--)
{
    for(j=0;j<=w[i]-1;j++)
        m[i][j]=m[i+1][j];
    for(j=w[i];j<=c;j++)
    {
        m[i][j]=max(m[i+1][j],m[i+1][j-w[i]]+v[i]);
    }
}
m[1][c]=m[2][c];
if(c>=w[1])
    m[1][c]=max(m[2][c],m[1][c-w[1]]+v[1]);

}

template <class Type>
void TrackBack(Type **m,int *w,int c,int n,int *x){
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    if(m[i][c]==m[i+1][c])
        x[i]=0;
    else
        x[i]=1;
}
}

int main()
{
int m[101][101]={0};
int x[101];
int n=5;
int c=10;
int w[5]={2,2,6,5,4};
int v[5]={6,3,5,4,6};

Knapsack(v,w,c,n,m);


return 0;
}
```

I an writing the algorithm of 01 Knapsack problem.

my Xcode says "No matching function for call to 'Knapsack'  "
I am stumbled by the red alarm.

I'm confused for passing arguments.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks a lot:)

Comment: it does not smell `C`. what you're cooking?

Comment: Please format your code properly - no one wants to wast time trying to make sense of badly formatted code.

Comment: And the missing word in Paul R's comment is ... *code*

Comment: An array of arrays of some type is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer to the type. See e.g  [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for an explanation why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least type of argument

```
int m[101][101]={0};
```

is not equivalent to `T **` where `T` is `int`.

When this array is passed by value as an argument it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and has type `int ( * )[101]`

Take into account that in any case this function is invalid. For example argument for second parameter w has 5 elements.

```
int w[5]={2,2,6,5,4};
```

The valid range of indices for it is `[0,4]`. `n` in the function call is equal to 5.

So this statement

```
int jMax=max(w[n]-1,c);
```

has undefined behaviour because you are using inadmissible index equal to 5.

```
template<class Type>
void Knapsack(Type *v,int *w,int c,int n,Type **m)
{
 int i,j;
    int jMax=max(w[n]-1,c);
//...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I couldn't give you upvote since I don't have enough reputation......

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid conversion:

```
int m[101][101]
...
Knapsack(v,w,c,n,m);
              // ^-- expects a Type **m
```

`m` can decay to type "pointer to array of 101 ints", but no further.

Answer (score 0):

You a little bit wrong with definition of functions

```
template < class Type>
void Knapsack(Type *v,int *w,int c,int n,Type m[][101])

template < class Type>
void TrackBack(Type m[][101],int *w,int c,int n,int *x)
```