# Runtime error, NxN Matrix Inverse in C

Tags: c, function, matrix, runtime-error, matrix-inverse

I am trying to write a function which gets a matrix and the dimension (square), and returns the inverse matrix in C.
Further, I will use it in solving a least square matrix solution function!

I have got most of the ideas and algorithms from online sources and tried to change them according to my program. When I build and run it (in Code::Blocks and ideone.com online compiler) I get either runtime error or irrelevant results.
Would be great if someone could help me.

Here is my code:

```
/* Inverse of NxN matrix */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double CalcDeterminant(int D, double matrix[D][D])
{
  /* Conversion of matrix to upper triangular */
int i, j, k;
double ratio, det=1;
for (I = 0; I < D; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < D; j++){
        if(j>i){
            ratio = matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];
            for(k = 0; k < D; k++){
                matrix[j][k] -= ratio * matrix[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
 }

 for(i = 0; i < D; i++)
 {
    det *= matrix[i][i];
 }

 return det;
}


double ** MatrixInverse(int size, double matrix[size][size])
{
int p,q,m,n,i,j,k;
double det;
double **m_inverse = (double **) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
 m_inverse[k] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
}

double **dummy = (double **) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
dummy[k] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
}
 /////////////////////////
 for (q=0;q<size;q++)
 {
     for (p=0;p<size;p++)
     {
         m=0;
         n=0;
         for (i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
             for (j=0;j<size;j++)
             {
                 if (i != q && j != p)
                 {
                    dummy[m][n]=matrix[i][j];
                    if (n<(size-2))
                    {
                       n++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n=0;
                        m++;
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
        det = CalcDeterminant(size-1, dummy);
        printf("%f\n", det);
        m_inverse[q][p]=pow(-1,(q+p))*det;
     }
  }
  for (i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
     for (j=0;j<size;j++)
     {
         dummy[i][j]=m_inverse[j][i];
     }
 }
   det=CalcDeterminant(size, matrix);
 for (i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
     for (j=0;j<size;j++)
     {
         m_inverse[i][j]= dummy[i][j] / det;
     }
  }


 for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    free(dummy[i]);
 free(dummy);    

return m_inverse;

}


int main()
{
int i, j;
int D = 5;
 // just an example matrix
double A[5][5] = {{1,2,3,4,6},
                  {6,1,5,3,8},
                  {2,6,4,9,9},
                  {1,3,8,3,4},
                  {5,7,8,2,5}};

printf("Original matrix\n");
for(i=0; i<D; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<D; j++)
    {   
    //  A[i][j] = i+j-5;
        printf("%f\t", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} 
double **A_inverse = MatrixInverse(D, A); 
printf("Inverse Matrix\n");
for(i=0; i<D; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<D; j++)
    {   
        printf("%f\t", A_inverse[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

det = CalcDeterminant(D, A);
printf("%f\n", det);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc`&friends.

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings. A warning you don't understand means you don't know what you are doing. Don't even think about maybe trying to to run the program until you are warning free.

Comment: @n.m.: I completely agree, But the standard warnings of most compilers are actually not sufficient - expecially for beginners. One should always have `-Wall` enabled, I generally recommend to add `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion`. The latter should be watched carefully.

Comment: If you're doing a least square fit for polynomials, there's way to avoid having to invert a matrix. [opls.rtf](http://rcgldr.net/misc/opls.rtf) .

Comment: @opls.rtf thanks for the comment. I am trying to solve a AX=B problem by calculating the pseudo-inverse of A. Do you know if the mentioned way would work in this case?

Comment: this line: 'for (I = 0; I < D; i++) {' does not compile.  I suspect it should be: 'for (i = 0; i < D; i++) {'

Comment: for readability by us humans, please consistently indent the code (never use tabs for indenting)  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'  Only place one variable declaration per statement.  for two main reasons.  1) for readability 2) so the variables are easy to document, so us humans know what/why each variable is used

Comment: as Olaf mentioned, do not cast the returned value from malloc.  Also, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: 'det = CalcDeterminant(D, A);'  is using 'det' which is not declared.  This is an error that results in a compile failure.  When asking about a runtime problem.  always post code the cleanly compiles, is minimal in size, and clearly demonstrates the problem.   always enable all the warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Comment: this line: 'det = CalcDeterminant(size-1, dummy);'  the second argument is if type double** but function is expecting different argument type

Comment: @MRM - The purpose of using orthogonal polynomials for a least squares fit [opls.rtf](http://rcgldr.net/misc/opls.rtf) is to avoid having to invert a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

This line contains a major error, one that will cause problems when `sizeof(int)` is not equal to `sizeof(int *)` (which is what usually happens on 64-bit platforms):

```
double **m_inverse = (double **) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

Same with the allocation for `dummy`.

You are allocating an array of *pointers* to int, so the correct here would be

```
double **m_inverse = malloc(sizeof(int *) * size);
```

---

Later you have a problematic line here:

```
det = CalcDeterminant(size-1, dummy);
```

Normally a pointer-to-pointer to some type is *not* the same an array-of-arrays of some type (see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558) to help you understand why).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So you mean I should insert (sizeof(int) size) instead ? Sorry I am not really into it.

Comment: @MRM Check your code, are you missing a closing parenthesis?

Comment: So, now it is done with allocation :) And now the determinant function. Shall I define it as CalcDeterminant(int D, double **matrix) ?  this case I get runtime error again, and don't know how to call it in main or the Inverse function.

Comment: @MRM If you declare the argument as a pointer-to-pointer then you get a problem when calling with the matrix from the `main` function, so no matter how you do it you will have to rework more than just the `CalcDeterminant` function. The easiest is probably to allocate and initialize the matrix in the `main` function, and let the function take a `double **` argument.

Comment: @MRM Also, you should learn how to use a debugger, because then you can catch the crash "in action", and see exactly where in your code it happens, and will also be able to check the function call stack *as well* as the values of involved variables.

Comment: I cannot define it in main, just as I said it would be at the end called by a function named "LeastSquare_MatrixSolve(A,X,b)" and then this function is called in another function. So basically I need to get rid of it here.

Comment: if using a debugger (a very good idea) then compile/link the code with the appropriate parameters so the debug info is available.  (for gcc and gdb, use -ggdb so outputs show line numbers, not addresses

Answer (score 1):

When allocating memory, always use the correct type for the size. You use `sizeof(int)` everywhere, even if `double` or *pointer* is required. Hint: use `sizeof(*<pointer you assign the result to>)`. This way, you always use the correct size.

Note: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends.

Comment: So as I said to Joachim, this is just a little part of a function, and there are 2 major function calls in que. And I'm a beginner (just worked with matlab!). If double ** Func(...) is a appropriate to return 2d array, what would you suggest to use? I have tried many types, all from online sources, but this was the most suitable one for the rest of the program.

Comment: @MRM: That is an array of pointers to `double`. I strongly recommend to read a C book; that will cover all the basics. Please understand we cannot provide a tutorial about that here, but that is vital to understand C. Without that knowledge, you will eventually fall into the next tar-pit. A 2D array is actually passed the same as a 1D array - by `<type> *`. The semantics are informal in C.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf. I was just following this: <https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/>

Comment: @MRM: Blindly following some internet recipe is **always** a bad idea. You might take such as a first idea, but then look up the concepts you do not understand in a book or tutorial (both can be found for free or money).