# Single malloc call for pointer to pointer "array" causes invalid writes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What I'm trying to do here (for educational purposes) is to have a pointer to a pointer that behaves like an array but with a single memory allocation. Valgrind is complaining about this code and if I do a longer version of this with several allocations I start having segfaults while debugging in gdb.

It's allocating 144 bytes (24 bytes for the 3 pointers, then 3*40 bytes for the integers). l[0] is +24 bytes from l, l[1] +40 from l[0] and so on.

Can someone enlighten me about what I'm getting wrong?

gcc -o program -g -ansi -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int **l;
    int i, j, k;
    int x = 3;
    int y = 10;
    size_t size_y = sizeof(int) * y;
    size_t x_ptrs = x * sizeof(int*);
    size_t mem_to_alloc = x_ptrs + x * size_y;

    l = malloc(mem_to_alloc);

    l[0] = (int*)l + x_ptrs;
    l[1] = (int*)l + x_ptrs + size_y;
    l[2] = (int*)l + x_ptrs + size_y * 2;

    k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < y; j++) 
        l[i][j] = (-k++)*12; /* just some number */

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("%.3d\n", l[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    free(l);
    l = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

valgrind ./program

```
==1593== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1593== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1593== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1593== Command: ./program
==1593== 
==1593== Invalid write of size 4
==1593==    at 0x4006E8: main (main.c:22)
==1593==  Address 0x51d5140 is 48 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,000 in arena "client"
==1593== 
000
-012
-024
-036
-048
-060
-072
-084
-096
-108

==1593== Invalid read of size 4
==1593==    at 0x400738: main (main.c:26)
==1593==  Address 0x51d5140 is 48 bytes inside an unallocated block of size 4,194,000 in arena "client"
==1593== 
-120
-132
-144
-156
-168
-180
-192
-204
-216
-228

-240
-252
-264
-276
-288
-300
-312
-324
-336
-348

==1593== 
==1593== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1593==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1593==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 144 bytes allocated
==1593== 
==1593== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1593== 
==1593== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1593== ERROR SUMMARY: 40 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: You should start by using correct variable names. Statements such as `l[i][j]` aren't really readable.

Comment: l[0] is +24 bytes from l -> this statement is wrong `l`  has the same address as `l[0]`

Comment: @ex0ns he's talking about the content assigned to `l[0]`, not its address.

Comment: First of all [you can't use a pointer to pointer as a contiguous array of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558), it simply will not work as you expect. Secondly, why not use a simple pointer and then use simple math to get the correct index? Something like e.g. `int *matrix = malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(int)); matrix[x * ysize + y] = 5;`

Comment: Do not! EIther use a 2D array, or allocate the array in two parts: the array of pointers then the rest. One problem is you might run into alignment problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be related to [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).

As you are doing `l[0] = (int*)l + x_ptrs;`, the offset `x_ptrs` is a number of bytes. Instead, it should be the number of integers you want to skip, since `l` is casted to `int*`.

Could you try `l[0] = (int*)l + 2*x;` ? This should work is the size of `int*` (most likely 8) is twice the size of `int` (most likely 4). The same logic is to be applied to `size_y`.

```
l[0] = (int*)l + 2*x;
l[1] = (int*)l + 2*x + y;
l[2] = (int*)l + 2*x + 2*y;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you add an integer and a pointer, the integer is scaled up by the size of what the pointer points to. So

```
l[1] = (int*)l + x_ptrs + size_y;
```

sets `l[1]` to `40 * sizeof(int)` bytes past `l`, i.e. `160` bytes past `l`. Since you only allocated `144` bytes, this goes outside the array bounds.

This automatic scaling is what allows you to step through an array with pointer arithmetic, e.g. `ptr++` to get to the next element of the array that `ptr` points to.