# Passing char ** as an argument

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Why this code doesn't work?
I have some old code and don't want to allocate `a` in the heap.

```
void test(char **str) {
   cout << str[0] << endl;
   cout << str[1] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char a[2][5];
    strcpy(a[0],"abc");
    strcpy(a[1],"def");

    char *str1 = (char *)a;
    test(&str1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: If you ever find the need to use a C-style cast in C++, then it's usually a sign of you doing something you should not be doing and that might lead to undefined behavior. If the compiler gives you an error or a warning, then using a C-style cast will just silence the compiler, the problem isn't really solved (you fix the symptom and not the disease).

Comment: Oh, and you might want to read e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456), which tries to describe the difference between an array of arrays and a pointer to pointer.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. There is no relation what-so-ever between 2D arrays and pointer-to-pointers. You may be confusing things with a common way to store strings: a one-dimensional array of pointers to char - because a pointer to the first element in such a one-dimensional array of pointers would be a `char**`.

Answer (score 5):

This code does not work because a pointer to pointer to `char` is *not* the same as a 2 by 5 array of `char`, with or without a cast:

- A pointer to pointer can be used as an array of pointers, i.e. its elements can be dereferenced with `*` operator
- A 2 by 5 array consists of ten items organized as two rows of five items each. None of these items is a pointer that could be dereferenced.

Here is how you can construct an array compatible with `char**`:

```
char a[2][5];
strcpy(a[0],"abc");
strcpy(a[1],"def");

char *str1[] = { a[0], a[1] };
test(str1);
```

Now `str1` is an array of `char` pointers, with two items. The first item is a pointer containing the address of `a[0]`; the second item is a pointer containing the address of `a[1]`. An array of pointers can be passed to a function expecting a pointer to pointer, hence your `test()` function works correctly.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/taGR74)

Answer (score 1):

#### Why ?

Because char `a[2][5]` is a 2 dimensional array stored as 10 contiguous chars. But parameter `char **str` expects an array of pointers to one dimensional arrays of chars.

[image]

#### Solution 1:

Keep the function as it is, but pass it an array of pointers to char:

```
...
char *str1[2];
str1[0]=a[0];
str1[1]=a[1];
test(str1);
```

#### Solution 2:

CHange the function to accept 2D arrays with 5 elements in the secund dimension (to pass an n dimensional array the last n-1 dimensions must be predefined):

```
void test(char str[][5]) {
    ...
}
int main() {
    ...
    test(a);
}
```

The inconvenience is that it is less flexible.

#### Solution 3

If your problem is specifically related to array of strings and not the more general issue of 2D array,  switch from `char*` to `std::string` and you'll make your life easier !

```
void test(string str[]) {
   ...
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string a[2] ={ "abc","def" };
    test(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++, you could change your `test` function to something like this:

```
template <int cols> void test(char arr2d[][cols]){
    /* whatever */
}
```

You'd then call it in your program passing `a` as argument (e.g `test(a)`), without any cast or other kind of transformation.