# return from incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

I get the warning Return from incompatible pointer type in line where I return sarray, why though? I have been trying to figure out for a while now.. I also get a warning for incompatible pointer type in line

```
( *iarray )[CHARACTER_LIMIT] = scanCode();
```

but I think if I fixed the first part, this would be easier to fix this one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_WORDS 9054 //Scope variables
#define CHARACTER_LIMIT 6
#define MAX_TRIPLETS 3018


char** scanCode(void)  
{
    FILE *in_file;
    int i = 0;
    static char sarray[MAX_WORDS][CHARACTER_LIMIT];
    in_file = fopen("message.txt", "r");
    for(i=0; i<WORD_COUNT_MAX; i++)    {
        fscanf(in_file,"%s", sarray[i]);
    }

    return sarray;
    fclose(in_file);
}

int main(void)
{

    char ( *iarray )[CHARACTER_LIMIT] = scanCode();  

    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your copy/paste of your code is either broken, or your actual code is - your lost the for keyword on this line: (i=0; i<WORD_COUNT_MAX; i++)  Can you doublecheck your posting so we know its correct?

Comment: To be clear, this is an error. Some compilers report errors as "warning" for unclear reasons.

Comment: [An array of arrays is not the same thing as a pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456).

Comment: The `fscanf` should use format string `"%5s"` to avoid buffer overflow, and `WORD_COUNT_MAX` should be `MAX_WORDS` (or smaller), and you currently don't have any way of letter `main` know how many words you actually read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sarray` is an array or arrays, which can decay to pointer to array, but not pointer to pointer. Converting `sarray` to `char**` should be an error.

Besides that, `scanCode()` returns a pointer to pointer to `char`. `iarray` is a pointer to array of `char` with length `CHARACTER_LIMIT`. These are not the same type, and the compiler is warning you about this.

You need to change either the return type of the function:

```
char (*scanCode(void))[CHARACTER_LIMIT] {
  ....
  return sarray;
}
```

Here, `sarray` decays to a pointer to array of length `CHARACTER_LIMIT`.

Comment: @M.M Strictly speaking, `char(*scanCode(void))[CHARACTER_LIMIT]`.

Comment: @M.M Fixed. It isn't very often that I write this kind of function prototype!

Comment: i made the changes char(*scancode())[CHARACTER_LIMIT] scanCode(void) and both return sarray; and return &sarray; but none of them works?

Comment: @digeridoo Sorry, you can just `return sarray`. It decays to pointer of the right type.