# Trouble with functions of arrays and pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to pass a pointer to an array to 2 functions and I'm getting a bunch of errors.
Here's a part of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct tetromino {
   int color;
   int location[4][2];
};

int main()
{
   int page[22][18]={0};
   struct tetromino block[7][4];
   block[1][0].color=13;
   block[1][0].location[0][0]=9;
   block[1][0].location[0][1]=-2;
   block[1][0].location[1][0]=9;
   block[1][0].location[1][1]=-1;
   block[1][0].location[2][0]=8;
   block[1][0].location[2][1]=0;
   block[1][0].location[3][0]=9;
   block[1][0].location[3][1]=0;
   tet_effect(page,block[1][0]);
   print(page);
}

void tet_effect(int *page,struct tetromino block)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
      page[block.location[i][0]][block.location[i][1]]=block.color;     
   }
   return;
}
void print(int *page)
{
   int i,j;
   system("cls");
   for (i=0;i<22;i++)
   {
      printf("|");
      for (j=0;j<18;j++)
      {
         SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),page[i][j]);
         printf("#");
      }
      printf("|\n");
   }
   printf("|");
   for (j=0;j<18;j++)
   {
      printf("-");
   }
   printf("|");
   return;  
}
```

And here are the errors:
[image: errors]

Why am I getting this and how do I it?

Comment: No, i'm not clicking on the link.

Comment: To begin with, where is the *prototype declaration* of the `tet_effect` function`? To continue, [a pointer to a pointer to something is not the same as a an array of array of something](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to provide the prototype of each function before calling them.

Then you need to change the parameter  `int *page` to `int (*page)[18]` because when `page` in `main` passed to these functions then it will converted to pointer to the first element of array `page`.
Since `array` is of type *an array of arrays*, therefore its first element is an array. So, `array` will be converted to pointer to array type, i.e `int (*)[18]`.

Prototype should be

```
void tet_effect(int (*page)[18], struct tetromino block);
void print(int (*page)[18]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that in your environment, you are using one of Microsoft's compilers, which resembles a C89 implementation.

In answering your questions, I will refer to the line-numbers as mentioned in the warnings and errors you've shared a picture of, as opposed to the line-numbers of the code you've shared.  (They are different.)

First warning (orange):

When you declare and define **tet_effect** on line 27, you define its type.  But the fact that it has also appeared *before* that definition (on line 22) means that it has already been deemed to have been declared to have the type **int()**.  (A function taking an unspecified number of arguments and returning an **int** value.)

First error (red):

On line 32 you have:

```
page[block.location[i][0]][block.location[i][1]]=block.color;
```

The type of **page** is **int ***, as declared on line 27.  Thus, the type of **page[***anything***]** is **int**.  An **int** is not an array nor a pointer, so the subsequent **[block.location[i][1]]** is not valid.

Second warning (orange):

This is the same kind of error as the earlier warning.  You attempt to declare and define **print** on line 36, but you'd accidentally declared it to have type **int()** on line 23, by calling it.

Second error (red):

This is the same kind of error as the earlier error.  The type of **page** is **int ***, so the type of **page[i]** is **int**, then the subsequent **[j]** is an error because an **int** is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to mention here...

1. You need to have a forward declaration of your functions. Without a forward declaration your compiler will not be able to know the function prototypes and as per the latest `C11` standard, implicit declaration of functions are not a part of the standard C anymore.
2. You pass the `page` as an `int *`, so later you cannot do `page[i][j]`, because, `page[i]` will give you an `int`, anyways.

That said, in your `main()`, `page` is of type `int [22][18]`, so you may not pass that to a simple `int *`, you will be needing the function parameter to be of matching type, something like `(int Innerpage[][18])` or something simmilar.