# Weird output when using char double pointer

Tags: c++

I get really weird output from the last cout statement, no idea what would be causing this:

```
char ex1_val = 'A';
char* ex1;
ex1 = &ex1_val;
cout << *ex1 << endl;
char** ex2;
ex2 = &ex1;
cout << *ex2 << endl;
```

Here's my output:

```
A
A����
```

Comment: isn't ** suppose to be a 2D array?

Comment: `cout` is not [tag:c]

Comment: `*ex2` is a pointer to c-style string, e.g. cout print chars until found a null-terminator

Comment: @AchmadJP A pointer to pointer to something is not the same as an array of arrays. See e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for an explanation of why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ex2` is declared as `char**`, which means it's *a pointer to a pointer to char*.

When you print the contents of `*ex2`, you're dereferencing it *once*, so type of `*ex2` is *a pointer to char*.

Effectively, the compiler assumes, that you want to print a *C-style string*, which is a `NULL`-terminated string. So it prints all bytes stored in memory, starting from `A` stored in `ex1_val`, followed by *random values* stored directly after that, until a `NULL` character is encoutered.

This is actually a very bad situation, as you never know *when* or *if* there's a `NULL` in memory. You might end up trying to access a memory area you're not allowed to use, which may result in crashing the application. This is an example of an *undefined behaviour* (*UB*).

To print out the actual contents of `ex1_val` via the `ex2` pointer, you'd need to make it like this:

```
cout << **ex2 << endl;
```

where `typeof(**ex2)` is an actual `char`.

Answer (score 1):

When you dereference `ex2` (in `*ex2`) you get a pointer to a `char` (i.e. `char*`), and the [`operator<<` overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) to handle `char*` outputs it as a C-style zero-terminated *string*.

Since `*ex2` doesn't point to a zero-terminated string, only a single character, you get *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do `cout << **ex2 << endl;`

`ex2`, as you have declared it, as a **pointer to a pointer** to a character. Doing `*ex2` only gets you the address of the pointer it is pointing to.