# C - free function crashes

Tags: c, memory-management, free, allocation

I tried checking the addresses and its all looking normal, printing works and everything else works as well.
But when it tries to free the memory, the program crashes.
CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FIRST_DIM 2
#define SECOND_DIM 3
#define THIRD_DIM 2
#define TOTAL 12
void getNums(float* pArr);
void sortArr(float* pArr);
void printArr(float* pArr);
int main(void)
{
    // Variable assignment
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;
    float*** pppArr = NULL;

    // Memory assignment
    pppArr = (float***)calloc(FIRST_DIM, sizeof(float**));
    if (!(pppArr))
    {
        printf("Failed Allocating Memory..\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < FIRST_DIM; i++)
    {
        *(pppArr + i) = (float**)calloc(SECOND_DIM, sizeof(float*));
        if (!(*(pppArr + i)))
        {
            printf("Failed Allocating Memory..\n");
            system("PAUSE");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < FIRST_DIM; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SECOND_DIM; j++)
        {
            *(*(pppArr + i) + j) = (float*)calloc(THIRD_DIM, sizeof(float));
            if (!(*(*(pppArr + i) + j)))
            {
                printf("Failed Allocating Memory..\n");
                system("PAUSE");
                return 1;
            }
            printf("%p && %d\n", *(*(pppArr + i) + j), **(*(pppArr + i) + j));
        }
    }
    printf("ASD");
    // Getting numbers, sorting them and printing them out
    getNums(**pppArr);
    sortArr(**pppArr);
    printArr(**pppArr);

    // End of program
    // Releasing memory
    for (i = 0; i < FIRST_DIM; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SECOND_DIM; j++)
        {
            free(*(*(pppArr + i) + j));
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < FIRST_DIM; i++)
    {
        printf("%p\n", *(pppArr + i));
        free(*(pppArr + i));
    }
    free(pppArr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/* This function gets values for the given array from the user */
void getNums(float* pArr)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%f", pArr + i);
        getchar();
    }
}

/* This function prints out the given array */
void printArr(float* pArr)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++)
    {
        printf("Number %d: %.2f\n", i, *(pArr + i));
    }
}

/* This function sorts the given array from lowest to highest*/
void sortArr(float* pArr)
{
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;
    float temp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < TOTAL - 1; j++)
        {
            if (*(pArr + j) > *(pArr + j + 1))
            {
                temp = *(pArr + j);
                *(pArr + j) = *(pArr + j + 1);
                *(pArr + j+ 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is there something im missing?

Comment: Oh no, a three-star programmer.

Comment: You do know that e.g. `*(pppArr + i)` is the same as `pppArr[i]`? Many find the latter easier to read and understand (it's also a couple of characters less to write).

Comment: [This link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) explains @Downvoter's comment. It can be read (at least that's what I do) as a suggestion to refactor this code to make it simpler.

Comment: It's really painful to read `*(*(pppArr + i) + j)`, rather than the equivalent and much more normal way to write it:  `pppArr[i][j]`.  This is an example of "fighting the language".

Comment: `TOTAL` --> `THIRD_DIM` in `getNums`, `sortArr` and `printArr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use pointers and dynamic allocation, the memory you allocate will most likely not be contiguous, but you will get separate memory areas for each allocation. That means when you treat it as one large contiguous memory area in your functions you exhibit *undefined behavior*.

An actual array, like

```
float arr[FIRST_DIM][SECOND_DIM][THIRD_DIM];
```

Now *that* will be contiguous.

See e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for a more "graphical" explanation of the difference between arrays of arrays, and pointers to pointers.

Comment: is there a way to make it contiguous and allocated in the heap as well?

Comment: @Administrator Allocate it as one big chunk, and use pointer arithmetic to access it with indexes. (something like e.g. `pArr[i * ROWS + j]`, but updated for your specific needs).

Answer (score 0):

This code is indexing out of bounds rather severely.  The memory allocated for `pppArr` has three levels of indirection.  It is not a multi-dimensional array (i.e., not an array of arrays), but is a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of pointers.  Three levels of indirection.  There are 6 separate `float` slices, each with 2 contiguous elements (i.e., `THIRD_DIM`).

When calling `getNums`, `sortArr`, and `printArr`, you are passing `**pppArr`.  This is equivalent to passing `pppArr[0][0]`, which points to a single 2-element sequence of `float` values.  The functions may only access `THIRD_DIM` elements, i.e. 2.  Instead, they are trying to access 12 elements (i.e., `TOTAL`), which of course corrupts memory and leads to undefined behavior.

As far as I can tell, it looks like you're trying to access the storage as a single one-dimensional array.  If so, then the easiest way to fix it is to eliminate 2 levels of indirection, and get rid of `FIRST_DIM`, `SECOND_DIM`, and `THIRD_DIM`, and just allocate a single, flat array with `LENGTH` elements.  The pointer would have type `float *`.