# Incompatible pointer type when passing a pointer of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to pass a pointer of pointer in order to modify its content in another function. In order to do this, I've read that I need to use a pointer of pointer of pointer so here's my "code" so far:

```
void modify(s8 ***strings){
    // Modifies the strings
}

void main(){
    s8 strings[9][95];
    for(i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; i < 95 ; i++){
            strings[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    modify(&strings);
}
```

s8 is a special type that is used by the MicroBlaze I'm using, is this a problem? I've also read that I need to use const but I don't understand where and why?

What about the size? Will I need to use a malloc inside modify in order to reserve a space in the memory? Or is it possible to just set the modify function as:

```
void modify(s8 *strings[9][95])
```

Right now, my issue is the following:
I get a warning on the last line (modify(&strings))about the pointer type that is incorrect.

```
passing argument 1 of 'modify' from incompatible pointer type
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all [an array of arrays is not the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456).

Secondly, if you jut want to modify the strings in the array you don't need to emulate pass by reference by passing a pointer to `strings`. All you need is to pass it as a normal argument, and of course modify the function suitably:

```
void modify(s8 strings[][95]){
    ...
}

int main(void){
    s8 strings[9][95];
    ...
    modify(strings);
    ...
}
```

In the `modify` function, you declare `strings` to be a pointer to an array of `95` characters. Then when you pass `strings` from the `main` function it decays to a pointer to its first element, which happens to be a pointer to an array of `95` characters.

If you wanted to be more explicit about the `strings` argument in `modify` being a pointer, you could do e.g.

```
void modify(s8 (*strings)[95]){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, passing the array as a normal argument is what I've done first but then my issue is that the last element (strings[7]) isn't what I set in the modify function once I get back into the main function. That's why I thought I was trying to do it wrong. Do you have any idea why? Meanwhile I'll try your syntax in order to see if I still have this issue!

Comment: @ArthurPenguin Sounds like you have a bug inside the function then, which is perhaps not related to the parameter passing.

Comment: Alternatively, use VLAs: `void modify(size_t x, size_t y, s8 strings[x][y])`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Finally had time to test your proposition, the issue was indeed coming from a misunderstanding between pointer of pointer and 2 dimensional array! Thanks :)