# Difference between char** and char[][]

Tags: c

I am trying to sort strings using stdlib qsort. I have created two sort functions sort1 and sort2. sort1 input argument is char** and sort2 input argument is char[][]. My program crashes when use sort1 function to sort array of strings.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;
    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

//program crashes
void sort1(char **A, int n1) {

    int size1 = sizeof(A[0]);
    int s2 = n1;
    qsort(A,s2,size1,compare);
}

//works perfectly
void sort2(char A[][10], int n1) {

    int size1 = sizeof(A[0]);
    int s2 = n1;
    qsort(A,s2,10,compare);

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

     char *names_ptr[5] = {"norma","daniel","carla","bob","adelle"};
     char names[5][10] = {"norma","daniel","carla","bob","adelle"};
     int size1 = sizeof(names[0]);
     int s2 = (sizeof(names)/size1);    
     sort1(names_ptr,5); //doesnt work
     sort2(names,5); //works
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: One ios a pointer, the other a 2D array. What is your **specific** problem you don't finmd answered in any C book or multiple times already here?

Comment: Read e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456).

Comment: I wanted to know why qsort is not complaining in 2D array , while the program crashed when the array was passed as **.

Comment: @Olaf Which warning are we talking about? I compiled with `-Weverthing` and none of the warnings have anything to do with the actual problem here.

Comment: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com) has a good explanation of the (admittedly sometimes confusing) relationship between arrays and pointers in C. Rule 1: Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @Olaf there would be no warnings, since `qsort` goes via `void *`, just silent UB due to casting to the compare function casting to the wrong type in the `sort1` case

Comment: @M.M: Yes, **that** one. Anyway, nothing not being answered here a hundret times already. OP does not show any own research effort. And `_tmain` is not the correct entry point. What is that Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qsort` function receives a pointer to the thing being sorted.  In `sort2` you are sorting *arrays of 10 char*. In `sort1` you are sorting *pointers to char*.

So the `compare` function is wrong for `sort1`, because the arguments are *pointers to pointers to char* (converted to `void *`), but you cast to *pointer to char*.

The `sort2` works because converting a *pointer to array of 10 char* into a *pointer to char* (via `void *`) produces a pointer that points to the first character of those 10.

You need to use a different compare function for each of these two cases, because you are sorting different things.