# 2D array make me STUCK

Tags: c++, arrays

I am struck while reading 2D array in C++ that we can declare in
Such a way:

```
month=4;.   // Initialize value of mont variable
void display(float [ ] [month] );   //declare
```

I want to know why the function doesn't need the size of fist dimension  ?

I ask this question on many forums but only get the way how to declare array like this . But never find the answer of why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because arrays when passed to functions are treated like *pointers* (to the arrays first element).

So an argument declaration like

```
float month[][X]
```

is equal to

```
float (*month)[X]
```

So `month` is a pointer to an array of `X` elements of type `float`.

This is because a "2d" array is really an array *of arrays*. C++ doesn't really have multi-dimensional arrays.

Also note that an [array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456). The decay to a pointer only happens for the outer array ("first dimension").