# Can't pass multidimensional array to structure

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
typedef struct arg_struct {
struct GPU_FFT *fft;
struct GPU_FFT_COMPLEX *base;
float **input;
float *output;
int number;
} arg_struct;

...

arguments[0].input = **Queue;
arguments[1].input = *(*(Queue)+QueueSize[0]);
```

My multidimensional array is `Queue[2][1025]`. I am trying to pass `Queue[0][0]` and Queue[1][0] into my arguments structure. It gives me `"error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float **’ from type ‘float’"` error. As a rookie programmer, I've tried so many variations but still couldn't figure out how to pass them.

By the way, `QueueSize[0]` is an integer which has value of 1025.

Comment: [An array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456).

Comment: I always thought arrays and pointers are related to each other.

Comment: Yes, C language has both arrays and pointers. A *lvalue* of array type decays into a pointer... and then, that's it.

Comment: *An* array can decay to a pointer to its first element. In your case `Queue` can decay to a pointer to an array of `1025` elements of type `float` (I guess), i.e. `Queue` is the same as `&Queue[0]` which is of the type `float (*)[1025]`. That in turn does *not* decay, because it's no longer an array.

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) to unlearn some bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem very easily, by making the `input` member a simple pointer:

```
float *input;
```

Then you can make each pointer point to the corresponding array of `Queue`:

```
arguments[0].input = Queue[0];
arguments[1].input = Queue[1];
```

Be careful though, the lifetime of `Queue` must be *at least* as long as the lifetime of `arguments`. If `Queue` goes out of scope then the pointers will be stray, and can no longer be used. If `Queue` can go out of scope then you need to create full arrays of (or allocate memory for) the `input` member, and copy the contents into that memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is big difference between `2d array` and `pointer to pointer`.

In your struct is `pointer to pointer`, so you have to init it like

```
arguments[0].input = malloc(sizeof(float *) * num_of_rows);
for (int i = 0; i < num_of_rows; i++)
{
    arguments[0].input[i] = malloc(sizeof(float) * num_of_cols);
}
```

Dont forget to free all the allocated memory. You can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for checking memory leaks.

---

`2D array` is sequence of bytes in memory

```
  0   1   2   3
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   0  // begins on address 1000
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   1  // begins on address 1004
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   2  // begins on address 1008
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   3  // begins on address 1012
+---+---+---+---+
```

while array of pointers, where every pointer can point to another part of memory

```
  0   1   2   3
+---+---+---+---+
| * | * | * | * |
+---+---+---+---+
  |   |   |   |
  |   |   |   |    0   1   2   3
  |   |   |   |  +---+---+---+---+
  |   |   |   -> | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   // begins on address 1000
  |   |   |      +---+---+---+---+
  |   |   -----> | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   // begins on address 2
  |   |          +---+---+---+---+
  |   ---------> | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   // begins on address 3045
  |              +---+---+---+---+
  -------------> | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   // begins on address 128
                 +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: "*In your struct is array of pointers*" well no, there is a pointer to a pointer (`float ** input`), nothing more, no array there.

Comment: Dear Filip, please take this as kind advise: Although English might not be your 1st language, still, this subject requires very accurate wording. A "*pointer to a pointer*" stays what it is: a pointer to a pointer. It *never* "*could by [an] array of pointers*". Take and keep this mantra: "*Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays!*" :-)

Comment: I thought that in context of 2D arrays it would be helpful to mention that it can be used as array of pointers.

Comment: If you *use* your head as a hammer doing so does not *make* it a hammer, right? ;-)

Comment: Sure not, Is it better now ? :-)