# Casting of 2D array to double pointer fails

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

Initialise a 2D array matrix as follows:

```
#define N 3
...
int matrix[N][N] = {};
```

The elements of the matrix can be accessed as follows:

```
for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    for(j=0; j<N; ++j)
        printf("%d ", *(*(matrix + i) + j) );
    printf("\n");
}
```

However the following code fails with a **segmentation fault**.

```
int **matrix_pointer = (int **)matrix;
for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    for(j=0; j<N; ++j)
        printf("%d ", *(*(matrix_pointer + i) + j) );
    printf("\n");
}
```

Please, Explain why or suggest an alternate method (with pointers) that works.

Comment: [A "2d array" is not the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558)

Comment: Casting in C mostly isn't the way to success, but just silencing the compiler.

Comment: As it should. Arrays are not pointers, nor is the converse true. Don't try to work around the type system.

Answer (score 0):

If defining

```
int matrix[3][5];
```

add then putting just `matrix` to the right of an `=`-operator, the array `matrix` decays (as every array would do) to the address of it's 1st element.

`matrix`'s 1st element is an `int[5]`. The address of an `int[5]` is `int(*)[5]`.

To if "*putting just `matrix` to the right of a `=`-operator*" then the left side of this assignment operation is expect to be a `int(*)[5]`:

```
int (*row)[5] = matrix;
```

---

Understanding the above it is obvious that doing

```
int ** ppi = matrix
```

cannot be correct as `int **` is not the same as `int(*)[5]`.

It assigns to a pointers from another pointer of different, will say incompatible type. The compiler would warn about this.

Apply a cast to the right hand side expression to fit the left hand side, is just telling the compiler to shut-up.