# How to correctly pass an 2D array pointer as argument?

Tags: c++

For the heads up: I am incredibly new with cpp. Being used to PHP and JS as work languages, I find pointers incredibly confusing.

So I have this Class called `Macierz`. The class is supposed to hold Matrixes of float variables and ought to have a constructor accepting an 2d array in order to print them into the field.

The field is declared like this
`float mx3[3][3];`

And the constructor has such declaration: `Macierz(float**);`
With the body using an additional function:

```
Macierz::Macierz(float** f) {
    length = 3;
    populateWith(f, length);
}

void Macierz::populateWith(float** val, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            mx3[i][j] = val[i][j];
}
```

In my `main()` function I want to declare the class with a created float array.
I try to do it as so, but It just won't work the way God intended:

```
float y[3][3] = { {1.00f, 2.00f, 3.00f}, { 4.00f, 5.00f, 6.00f }, { 7.00f, 8.00f, 9.00f } };

Macierz m5(y);
```

This is the base template of what I want to do. I've tried making the `y` variable a double pointer, a regular pointer, passing via reference and it just won't kick.

What would be the most prober way to pass this variable?

Any help will be amazing, I am really a noob in this language.

Comment: An array of arrays is not equivalent to a pointer to pointer. See e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for a simple drawing of the difference.

Comment: And to help you I suggest you stat using the standard library and its [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). In your case, since the arrays is of a compile-time fixed size you could use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Something like `std::array<std::array<float>, 3>, 3> y = { ... }`. Then just pass references to the type as arguments and copy it as one would normally copy a variable (using assignment).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For now the project has many elements in it using the float[][] type thing, therefore changing the base way it works would add alot more work into it. If I had the chance now, Id do it with Vectors probably :P But thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. But that isn't recursive.

For `y` in your example, the decay is to a pointer to the first element of `y`, which is equal to `&y[0]`. That is a pointer to an *array*, and will have the type `float(*)[3]`, which is the type you need for your arguments:

```
Macierz::Macierz(float (*f)[3]) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tho found another way by rewriting the table into a pointer to pointers one. Check my answer below. Turned out to be quite of a basic answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by copying the float into a pointer-to-pointer types

```
float y[3][3] = { {1.00f, 2.00f, 3.00f}, { 4.00f, 5.00f, 6.00f }, { 7.00f, 8.00f, 9.00f } };

    float** x = 0;
    x = new float*[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        x[i] = new float[3];

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            x[i][j] = y[i][j];
        }
    }

    Macierz m5(x);
```

Comment: Don't forget to `delete[]` the memory you `new[]`. Its also an extra step which of course will have an impact on performance. And you don't need the actual copying of the values, just do e.g. `x[i] = y[i]` in the outer loop.

Comment: Sure. Thank you!