# Pass two-dimensional array to function as single pointer and access to every cell of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to make a function which can accept one-dimensional arrays and two-dimensional arrays. I also need to do that with single pointer as argument of this function.

If someone will ask, I solved my problem with double pointer as argument on function `matrix`, but now I have to do this in other way. 
I was thinking about passing array of pointers and in my function assign every pointer (of row) to temporary one-dimensional array. I'm not familiar with C language, so maybe I did some stupid mistake, but I believe `tmpTab = &tab[i];` this line of code should work, but it doesn't, because I get junk on output.

```
void matrix(double* tab, int n, int l) {
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0;
    int i, j, isCol = 1, isRow = 1;
    double *tmpTab;

    if (l >= n || l < 0) { isRow = 0; }
    if (l >= n || l < 0) { isCol = 0; }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tmpTab = &tab[i];
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("\n%i: %lf", j, tab[j]);
            if (tab[j] < S || tab[j] > E) count1++;
            if (isRow && i == l && tab[j] >= S && tab[j] <= E) count2++;
            if (isCol && j == l && tab[j] >= S && tab[j] <= E) count3++;
            if (i == j && tab[j] >= S && tab[j] <= E) count4++;
            if (i > j && tab[j] >= S && tab[j] <= E) count5++;
            if (i + j == n - 1 && tab[j] >= S && tab[j] <= E) count6++;
        }
    }
}
```

Function to allocate my array:

```
double **allocate_array(int n) {
    double **tab;
    tab = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tab[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    double **tab;
    tab = read_array("dane.txt", &N);
    print_array(tab, N);
    matrix((double *)tab, N, 2);
}
```

Read from file works properly, print_array also. 
This is output of my program for research.

```
3.30 2.30 2.10 3.30 3.40                                                                                                3.30 2.30 2.10 3.30 3.40                                                                                                3.30 2.30 2.10 3.30 3.40                                                                                                3.30 2.30 2.10 3.30 3.40                                                                                                3.60 2.60 2.60 3.60 3.50                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0: 0.000000                                                                                                             1: 0.000000                                                                                                             2: -6277435991103237715486889255272272650483169294881725067238215516160.000000                                          3: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          4: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          0: 0.000000                                                                                                             1: 0.000000                                                                                                             2: -6277435991103237715486889255272272650483169294881725067238215516160.000000                                          3: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          4: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          0: 0.000000                                                                                                             1: 0.000000                                                                                                             2: -6277435991103237715486889255272272650483169294881725067238215516160.000000                                          3: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          4: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          0: 0.000000                                                                                                             1: 0.000000                                                                                                             2: -6277435991103237715486889255272272650483169294881725067238215516160.000000                                          3: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          4: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          0: 0.000000                                                                                                             1: 0.000000                                                                                                             2: -6277435991103237715486889255272272650483169294881725067238215516160.000000                                          3: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000                                          4: -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.000000
```

Comment: A pointer to a pointer is ***not*** the same as an array of arrays (a "multi-dimensional" array). See e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for an explanation about why.

Comment: By the way, `tab = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double) * n)` is wrong for two reasons: First of all you don't allocate the size of pointers; Secondly in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I'm not wrong I pass this to function: ```
| matrix[0] | matrix[1] | matrix[2] | ... |
``` and I should access to their addresses by ```matrix[i]```, becouse it points me memory where my row is stored.

Comment: The problem is this: `matrix((double *)tab, N, 2)`. `tab` is a pointer to a pointer, you have allocated it as an array of pointers not an array of values. It can't be used as an array of arrays (what e.g. `double tab[X]Y];` would be) or an array of values.

Comment: I'm also very unclear about what problem you're trying to solve? What is the `matrix` function supposed to do? Why can't it take a `double **tab` argument?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then I will have another problem, becouse I need dynamic allocated "array"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Matrix function count some things and print it to console, but for clear I cut most of the lines of ```printf``` functions. ```double **tab``` could be argument and I did it for the first time, but my professor told me that I should do this in another approach...

Comment: @NorbertIncze I will try the 3rd option, becouse maybe it will solve my problem

Comment: You have a `\n` in your only `printf`. Are you sure that the output is 1 very long line?