# Why am I getting the C++ no known conversion error here?

Tags: c++

This is the relevant code:

```
void init(int f, int h, std::vector<std::vector<double> > **offsets) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  for (int i = 0; i < 2 * h + 1; i++) { // for all frames                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    // vector of (x, y, d)'s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      for (int x = 0; x < W; x++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        random_offsets(offsets[y][x]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        print_vecs(offsets[y][x]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             


int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

  int h = 6;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Halide::Runtime::Buffer<uint8_t> frame[2*h + 1];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  int f = 6;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  for (int i = -h; i < h; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    frame[i] = load_image("test1/small/" + std::to_string(f + i) + ".png");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  W = frame[0].width();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  H = frame[0].height();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

  std::vector<std::vector<double> > offsets[H][W];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  init(6, h, offsets);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

I create an `offsets` 2d array and pass it into the init function. But this gives the following error upon compilation:

```
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<std::vector<double> > [H][W]' to                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      'std::vector<std::vector<double> > **' for 3rd argument                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
void init(int f, int h, std::vector<std::vector<double> > **offsets) {
```

How can I fix this?

---

After following one of the comments and changing to vector ...(H, vector...)...
I have the following code altogether:

```
void random_offsets(std::vector<std::vector<double> > &offsets) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    std::vector<double> offset;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    offset.push_back(W/3 * ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    offset.push_back(W/3 * ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    offsets.push_back(offset);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             


void init(int f, int h, std::vector<std::vector<double> > &offsets) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  for (int i = 0; i < 2 * h + 1; i++) { // for all frames                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    // vector of (x, y, d)'s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for (int y = 0; y < H; y++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      for (int x = 0; x < W; x++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        random_offsets(offsets[y][x]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        print_vecs(offsets[y][x]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             


int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

  int h = 6;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  Halide::Runtime::Buffer<uint8_t> frame[2*h + 1];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  int f = 6;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  for (int i = -h; i < h; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    frame[i] = load_image("test1/small/" + std::to_string(f + i) + ".png");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  W = frame[0].width();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  H = frame[0].height();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

  std::vector<std::vector<double>> offsets(H, std::vector<double>(W));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  init(6, h, offsets);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
init.cpp:43:2: error: no matching function for call to 'random_offsets'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        random_offsets(offsets[y][x]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
init.cpp:14:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator<double> >::value_type'                                                                                                                                                                      
      (aka 'double') to 'std::vector<std::vector<double> > &' for 1st argument                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
void random_offsets(std::vector<std::vector<double> > &offsets) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     ^
```

Seems like what I really needed was, assuming that the  2d array of 2d vectors is not going to work, was:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > > offsets(H, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double> > > (W, std::vector<std::vector<double> > (k, std::vector<double> (3))));
```

Comment: An array of array is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer, see [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558) for a description of why. Array decay only happens for the *first* array "dimension".

Comment: Besides, do you really need a "2d" array of a "2d" vector (making it, essentially, a ***4d*** array). I think what you really want is something like `std::vector<std::vector<double>> offsets(H, std::vector<double>(W));` That's just a guess though since you don't tell us anything about the problem you try to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude offsets is the initialization to find the k-nearest neighbors for each pixel in an image.

Comment: @zengod, you should ask a new question for your edit. But your problem is that `offsets[y][x]` is not a `std::vector`, you are indexing so it is actually a `double`. You then pass this double to `random_offsets` which expects a `vector<vector<...`. This won't work ...

Answer (score 1):

This `std::vector<std::vector<double> > **offsets` doesn't do what you think it does. This is a pointer to a pointer to a `std::vector...`. What you are likely looking for is pass by reference:

```
void init(int f, int h, std::vector<std::vector<double> > &offsets)
```

This fits how you are calling this function and how you use the object internally.

There is a pretty good overview of this here: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) but I would highly recomend that you investigate a good c++ book here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: no, `offsets` is a 2d array of `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`

Comment: @user3365922, a pointer is not enough information to tell you that. What if this is initialized like this: `offsets = &(new std::vector<std::vector...)`? Then its still a `**` but it is certainly not a 2d array ...