# Initialization from incompatible pointer type warning when assigning to a header given array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

GCC gives me an 'Initialization from incompatible pointer type' warning when I use the following code.

```
 #include "mnist.h"
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {

    double** inputLayer = train_image; 

}
```

train_image is a bidimensional array given by mnist header file that according to the autor is like that

- train image : train_image[60000][784] (type: double, normalized, flattened);

Comment: Two dimensional array *is not* a pointer to pointer.

Comment: While array decays to pointers to their first element, in this case the array `train_image` decays to a pointer to an *array* (which does *not* decay further). A pointer to an array is not the same as a pointer to a pointer. [This old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) tries to show the difference.

Comment: How can I change the code to work?

Answer (score 0):

array is not pointer to pointer.

```
int main()
{
    double *pointer = &train_image[0][0];
    double **inputLayer = &pointer; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this

```
double train_image[60000][784];
```

then a pointer to its first element should be declared like

```
double ( *inputLayer )[784] = train_image;
```

That is the expression `train_image` used as an initializer has the type `double ( * )[784]`.

If it is needed then you can reinterpret the two-dimensional array as a one dimensional array using the following pointer declaration

```
double *inputLayer = ( double * )train_image;
```