# Access Violation with OCCI next() and setDataBuffer()

Tags: c++, occi

unfortunately I can't see the forest for the trees and need help. I call a result set via a SELECT statement, which has 70 columns. I initialize my buffer for all 70 columns which are chars and set them with setDataBuffer. Unfortunately I can only retrieve 15-17 records. After that I get an Access Violation error message. If I try next(1000) it does not work at all. I think it has something to do with the pointers but I don't see the error. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
            #pragma region Arrays
            char*** data_array  = new char**[70];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
            {
                data_array[i] = new char*[1000];
                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j)
                {
                    data_array[i][j] = new char[500];
                }
            }

            ub2**   size_array  = new ub2 * [70];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
            {
                size_array[i] = new ub2[1000];
            }

            sb2**   ind_array   = new sb2 * [70];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
            {
                ind_array[i] = new sb2[1000];
            }

            ub2**   rc_array    = new ub2 * [70];
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
            {
                rc_array[i] = new ub2[1000];
            }
            #pragma endregion

            #pragma region setDataBuffer
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
            {
                resultSet->setDataBuffer(i + 1, data_array[i][0], OCCI_SQLT_STR, 500, size_array[i], ind_array[i], rc_array[i]);
            }
            #pragma endregion

            try
            {
                ResultSet::Status resultSetStatus = resultSet->next(25);
                if (resultSetStatus == ResultSet::Status::DATA_AVAILABLE)
                {
                    unsigned int rowCount = resultSet->getNumArrayRows();
                    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row)
                    {
                        for (unsigned int column = 0; column < 70; ++column)
                        {
                            auto value =  data_array[column][row];
                            auto vsize = *size_array[column];

                            std::string cellContent(value, vsize);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException& sqlEx)
            {
                std::string msg = sqlEx.getMessage();
                int i = 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your allocation of `data_array`, because you create it as a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), not a contiguous array of memory as needed by [`setDataBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28390/reference027.htm#LNCPP21584).

If you want do use dynamic allocation using `new[]` I suggest something like this instead:

```
using data_type = int8_t[1000][500];
auto data_array = new data_type[70];
```

Then each element of `data_array` will be a contiguous area of memory, `1000 * 500` bytes large.

---

If you want to know the difference between an array of arrays (as in my solution) and your pointer to pointer (jagged array), see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456).