# Why do I get compilation error while passing a matrix to a function

Tags: c, compilation, c99

May I know where am I wrong? I need to pass the matrix to the function for print it, but when I compile it I get some errors.. Since I'm passing a matrix i have used a **p but I dunno why I get compilation error.

This is the compilation error:

```
ricorsione_TdE_19_02_2018.c: In function ‘main’:
ricorsione_TdE_19_02_2018.c:26:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stampa’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   26 |  stampa(M,i,j);
      |         ^
      |         |
      |         int (*)[2]
ricorsione_TdE_19_02_2018.c:4:19: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[2]’
    4 | void stampa(int **p, int i, int j);
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 2

void stampa(int **p, int i, int j);

int m=0,n=0;

int main(){

    int i,j,M[MAX][MAX];

    for (i=0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (j=0; j < MAX; j++){
            printf ("Inserisci il valore della cella M[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (j=0; j < MAX; j++){
            printf("%d", M[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    stampa(M,i,j);

    return 0;
}

void stampa(int **p, int i, int j) {

    for (i=0; i < MAX; i++){
        for (j=0; j < MAX; j++){
            printf("%d", p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always please include the actual errors you get. Copy-paste them (as text) in *full* and *complete*. Also please add comments on the lines in the code *where* you get the errors.

Comment: A hint though: [An array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456).

Comment: Please *edit your question* instead, not post as comments.

Comment: So how can I fix that problem using pointers?

Comment: The compiler is telling you the exact type it's passing to the function ("but argument is of type ‘int (*)[2]’"). You can use that type for your argument.

Comment: so i have to write: void stampa(int (*)[MAX], int i, int j); ??

Comment: `void stampa(int (*p)[2], int i, int j);`

Comment: Instead if the matrix was not of the same dimension, I mean it was m[5][5], (so that I had to write int (*p)[5]), but it was like m[5][6], how could I could it with pointer? should I do (**p)[5][6]? or just (*p)[5][6]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) linked, a matrix of constant bounds is stored differently than a pointer to a pointer, hence these types are incompatible.

The fix is pretty simple, just change the prototype:

```
void stampa(int p[MAX][MAX], int i, int j);
```