# **array vs array[][]: are they both 2D arrays?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

My teacher told me that int **array is not a 2D array, it is just a pointer to a pointer to an integer.
Now, in one of my projects I have to dynamically allocate a 2D array of structs, and this is how it is done:

```
struct cell **array2d = (struct x **)calloc(rows, sizeof(struct x *));
    
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    array2d[i] = (struct x *)calloc(j, sizeof(struct x));
}
```

But here we return a pointer to a pointer to the struct, so how is this a 2D array?

Before using dynamic allocation, I had a statically allocated array of the form:
array2d[][]

Now that I replaced it by dynamic allocation, I also replaced array2d[][] by **array2d.
Every function that takes array2d[i][j] als argument now returns an error saying the types don't match.

Could someone explain me what is happening here? What is the difference between **array and array[m][n] and why is the compiler complaining?

Comment: First of all, C doesn't have "2D" arrays. It does have nested arrays, arrays of arrays, which unfortunately are frequently talked about as multi-dimensional arrays. And secondly, an array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer (also sometimes known as a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)).  See e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for a somewhat visual representation of the differences.

Comment: And to help you understand things a little better, there are two things you need to know: 1) All arrays (proper arrays) can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. So if we have e.g. `int array[X];` then using plain `array` is the same as `&array[0]`, with the type `int *`; And 2) For any array *or pointer* `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`, which means that all "array" indexing is really pointer arithmetic. These two things is what sometimes can make arrays and pointers seem similar.

Comment: Both or neither, depending on whom you ask. A 2D array is an abstraction. It only exist in people's heads (and details vary between people's heads). It is not a language construct. Not in C at any rate. Both `int **array` and `int array[m][n]` may or may not implement your preferred abstraction to some degree or another. But they are different, incompatible things as far as C is concerned.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < i; i++) {`  - When do you expect `i` to be less than `i`? Will this loop ever run? Given that `i` appears before the loop, it looks like the `i` locally scoped to your list is shadowing the `i` in the outer scope.

Comment: @Chris I fixed it to make the example clearer.

Comment: Duplicate: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I took a look at your answer, thank you. But what if the array elements themselves are pointers (to structs) and not just numbers?

Comment: Style note:  [Don't cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @HeloKitay Then each element is a pointer, with an arrow to the structure. And if the structure have pointers, there's more arrows to whatever they point to. And so on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so in't it in this case the same as **2darray?

Answer (score 3):

They're thoroughly different things.

An array is a sequence of values of the same type stored one after another in memory.

In C, an array is more or less interchangeable with a *pointer to its first element* — `a[0]` is `*a`,
`a[1]` is `*(a+1)`, etc. — at least when we're talking about one-dimensional arrays.

But now consider:

```
int a[3][3];
```

in this case, `a` contains nine elements, contiguous in memory. `a[0][0]` through `a[0][2]`, then `a[1][0]` immediately after, up until `a[2][2]`.

If you pass `a` to a function, it would fit into a parameter type of `int *` or `int[3][3]` or `int [][3]` (knowing the "stride" of the second dimension is absolutely necessary to doing the math to look up a given element).

On the other hand:

```
int *b[3];
b[0] = malloc(...);
b[1] = malloc(...);
b[2] = malloc(...);
```

in this case, `b` is an array of 3 elements, each of which is a pointer to an array of 3 elements. You still access it like `b[0]0]` or `b[1][2]`, but something completely different is happening under the hood. The elements aren't all stored contiguously in memory, and `*b` isn't any of them, it's a pointer. If we were to pass `b` to a function, we would receive it with a parameter of type `int **` or `int *[]`. Knowing the length of each row in advance isn't necessary, and in fact each row could have a different length from the others. Some of the rows could even be null pointers, with no storage behind them for integers.

Comment: For your example `*a` is the same as `a[0]` -- you need `**a` to be the same as `a[0][0]`.  The expression `a[1]` is perfectly meaningful; it is a pointer to the second subarray of `a` and will decay to `&a[1][0]` (a pointer to the first element of that subarray) in most cases.