# Comparing SVD algorithm in C (svdlibc) with MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab, svd

I wanted to compare the SVD (singular value decomposition) algorithm C code from https://github.com/lucasmaystre/svdlibc to [MATLAB SVD](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.svd.html) implementation.

C code is in fact [SVDLIBC](https://alize.univ-avignon.fr/svn/LIA_RAL/trunk/LIA_SpkDet/CovIntra/src/SVDLIBC/Manual/index.html).

I built the C project without problems, and replaced the `main()` with my simple test:

```
#define M (4)
#define N (4)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Test array
    double test[M][N] = {
            { 1.0e-07* 0.609979111792474,  1.0e-07* 0.442691149480391,  1.0e-07* 0.063440080518362, 1.0e-07*-0.346712389824400,},
            { 1.0e-07* 0.442691149480391,  1.0e-07* 0.484281334855962,  1.0e-07* 0.055069632301392, 1.0e-07*-0.300966260855239,},
            { 1.0e-07* 0.063440080518362,  1.0e-07* 0.055069632301392,  1.0e-07* 0.107891781688921, 1.0e-07*-0.043130123212035,},
            { 1.0e-07*-0.346712389824400,  1.0e-07*-0.300966260855239,  1.0e-07*-0.043130123212035, 1.0e-07* 0.335714519434403 }
    };

    // Create the input matrix
    DMat D = svdNewDMat(M, N);
    // Initialize with data
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
        D->value[i]=test[i];

    // We need sparse S matrix as input to main algo
    SMat S = svdConvertDtoS(D);

    // Other inputs (values taken from original main() )
    int dimensions = M;
    int iterations = 0;
    double las2end[2] = {-1.0e-30, 1.0e-30};
    double kappa = 1e-6;

    // Calculate SVD algo
    SVDRec R = svdLAS2(S, dimensions, iterations, las2end, kappa);

    // Print results from R
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("U[%d][%d] = %+.15f  ", i,j, R->Ut->value[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        printf("S[%d] = %+.15f  ", i, R->S[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("V[%d][%d] = %+.15f  ", i,j, R->Vt->value[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, the result I get is:

```
U[0][0] = +0.669469029923469  U[0][1] = +0.581137555529811  U[0][2] = +0.083280213210335  U[0][3] = -0.455142577236855  
U[1][0] = +0.000000000000000  U[1][1] = +0.000000000000000  U[1][2] = +0.000000000000000  U[1][3] = +0.000000000000000  
U[2][0] = +0.000000000000000  U[2][1] = +0.000000000000000  U[2][2] = +0.000000000000000  U[2][3] = +0.000000000000000  
U[3][0] = +0.000000000000000  U[3][1] = +0.000000000000000  U[3][2] = +0.000000000000000  U[3][3] = +0.000000000000000
```

Expected values calculated using MATLAB are (transposed):

```
  -0.669469029923469  -0.581137555529811  -0.083280213210335   0.455142577236855
   0.000000000000000   0.112110571326639  -0.992948073424445  -0.038540151524073
  -0.000000000000000  -0.612706096707861  -0.038540151524073  -0.789370569363666
   0.742839967942847  -0.523738102878401  -0.075054555430211   0.410187756191207
```

Seems like I get only the first row, and that one is OK (only the sign is inverted).
But why are the other values all zero?

Am I handling the input array properly? The input `DMat D` is declared [here](http://Am) as:

```
struct dmat {
  long rows;
  long cols;
  double **value; /* Accessed by [row][col]. Free value[0] and value to free.*/
};
```

Comment: What do you observe when removing all the `1.0 e-7` in the matrix ? The eigenvectors should be unchanged, a difference could indicate a particular rounding issue (or a test issue)  in the algorithm.

Comment: @Damien, the vectors are unchainged.

Comment: What eigenvalues did you get in both cases, matlab and C? In the documentation, it is mentioned that *This algorithm has the drawback that the low order singular values may be relatively imprecise*.

Comment: What is the shape of `D`?  i.e. 1D, 2D?  your initialization with `test` (2 2D) suggests you are only populating part of `D`.

Comment: @ryyker D is declared [here](https://github.com/lucasmaystre/svdlibc/blob/0abfaf8da00ed14f2e275bb4435ca0844f89f936/svdlib.h#L58) as `dmat`.

Comment: @ryyker `value` is `double**`. I think the code should work?

Comment: Here is how the input arrays are initialized: https://github.com/lucasmaystre/svdlibc/blob/0abfaf8da00ed14f2e275bb4435ca0844f89f936/svdlib.c#L51.

Comment: `double **value; /* Accessed by [row][col]. Free value[0] and value to free.*/` indicates that `value` is indeed created as a 2D array.  Its initialization is not being done correctly.

Comment: I am not familiar with these algorithms, but `int iterations = 0;` looks suspicious.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, it may be a red herring.  I see other example implementations of using `0` as a value for _iterations_ in [svdLAS2()](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/ch.akuhn.edu.mit.tedlab.Svdlib/svdLAS2)

Comment: Note regarding iterations: `// number of algorithm iterations supplying 0 will use the input matrix shape to determine iterations`  (from [here](https://crates.io/crates/svdlibrs))

Comment: Can you post the code for svdNewDMat? I'm curious to see how the allocation is coded.

Comment: @JamesTursa Linke is already above in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

One problem, based on seeing how `value` is defined:

```
struct dmat {
  long rows;
  long cols;
  double **value; /* Accessed by [row][col]. Free value[0] and value to free.*/
};
```

In this call `DMat D = svdNewDMat(M, N);`, member `value` is created as a dynamically allocated 2D array.

This then is not properly initializing `value` with `test`

```
 // Create the input matrix
    DMat D = svdNewDMat(M, N);
    // Initialize with data
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
        D->value[i]=test[i];
```

Change to the initialization to assign all values in `testtest[i][j]` to corresponding locations within `D->value[i][j]`:

```
 // Create the input matrix
    DMat D = svdNewDMat(M, N);
    // Initialize with data
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
       for(int j=0; j<N;  j++)
           D->value[i][j]=test[i][j];
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried that, it gives the same result.

Comment: @Danijel - I am not suggesting that you edit that section in your post,(that would be a bad idea.)   but why did you choose to show a partial initialization if you knew it was incorrect?

Comment: I didn't think it's incorrect. After all, it works the same.

Comment: @Danijel -  There is something else, in addition to the incomplete population of `value` problem.   Have you seen my comment on `iterations` being set to zero?   Is that a valid value to pass as an argument into `svdLAS2()`?

Comment: Yes, `iterations` ends up set to `dimensions` if set to 0, so setting it to 0 seems OK.

Comment: @Danijel - I unfortunately do not have time or expertise on library to be of any further help. At this point, I suggest you pour thorough the documentation.  Make sure where your functions return a value, that you check that value to determine if the function worked as expected.  Turn on all warning (i.e. `-Wall` in gcc)  and run your code in debug with break points.  If you have source for the functions, then compile the library into a debuggable module as well, enabling you to step into the actual library functions.