# How to dynamically allocate multi-dimensional array on variable that's already been declared in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

I have a structure that contains a pointer to a 2d-array that will be allocated in an initialization function. It's also important to allocate this array in a contiguous block of memory.

I know to allocate a contiguous block of memory as a 2d-array like this:

```c
double (*array)[cols] = malloc(rows* sizeof *array);
```

However I need to do this on an already declared variable. For example:

```c
typedef struct {
    double **data;
    /* other members */
} MyType;

MyType* init_function(/* args */)
{
    /* more initializing */
    MyType* foo = malloc(sizeof(MyType));

    double (*array)[3] = malloc(3 * sizeof(*array));
    foo->data = array;
    /* more initializing */
}
```

I would think this would work, but my program crashes as soon as it attempts to either read or write from `foo->data`. I've printed the pointer address to both `array` and `foo->data` and they are identical, and I'm also able to print the contents of `array`, however attempting to access `foo->data[0][0]` causes the program to crash. I'm unsure why this won't work, or how to allocate the memory in this fashion on `foo->data` which is already declared.

Comment: That won't work for `data`, as it's really an array of *pointers* rather than an array of arrays. `data` is similar to a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). See e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456) for the difference between the two.

Comment: `double (*array)[3] = malloc(3 * sizeof(*array));` Your compiler warned you about this assignment. You should not have proceeded to run  the program.

Comment: @n.m.: Why do you think the compiler warned about `double (*array)[3] = malloc(3 * sizeof(*array));`? Did you mean `foo->data = array;`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes sorry copied the wrong line.

Comment: yep, totally glossed over the warning. should have seen that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `data` member must be the same as the allocated object. It must be a pointer to 3 element array of `double`.

```
typedef struct {
    double (*data)[3];
    /* other members */
} MyType;
```