# Write a function which accepts as input a 2D integer array and returns the summation of all elements in it

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I want to write a function that accepts as input a 2D integer array (denoted by double asterisks) and the size of that array as n (number of arrays) and m (size of each array).
As output, the function should return the summation of all elements in the array. Remember, arrays in C are 0-indexed!

My code is as follows, but it always output incorrect results.

```
int two_d_sum(int ** arr, int n, int m) {
    int sum = 0, t;
    
    int* p = &(**arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j){
            t = *(p + i*m + j);
            sum += t;
        }
    }
    return sum;
} /* two_d_sum() */
```

This function is called as follows:

```
int main() {
    printf("Enter the number of arrays in the array (n): ");
    int size_n;
    scanf("%d%*c", &size_n);

    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array in the array (m):");
    int size_m;
    scanf("%d%*c", &size_m);

    int **arr = (int **)malloc(size_n * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < size_n; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(size_m * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < size_m; j++) {
            int num;
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d%*c", &num);
            arr[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
  
    // ...
    int sum = two_d_sum(arr, size_n, size_m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you pass for `arr` ? Show more code.

Comment: "arrays in C are 0-indexed!": not sure that this reminder is really necessary :-)

Comment: `arr` is a 2D-integer array, such as int arr[5][9].

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Please show how you pass it.

Comment: [An array of arrays is ***not*** the same thing as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456). An array of arrays decays to a pointer to arrays. For example an array like `int arr[5][9]` will decay to the type `int (*)[9]`. Your compiler should have been complaining about you passing the wrong argument type.

Comment: Why aren't you using `arr[i][j]` inside the function as you are doing in `main`?

Comment: `scanf("%d%*c", &num)` is wrong. Don't do the `%*c` bit, it's just not needed in your case (and could lead to weird problems). The `%d` format automatically skips leading white-space, like the newline left over from the previous input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As coded, you assume the array is a flat 2D array (an array of arrays of `int`) but given the prototype for the function provided to you, `arr` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `int`, which may be implemented with independently allocated arrays (EDIT: and indeed that is how you allocate this indirect 2D array in the `main()` function).

You should just use the pointers, which is very simple: all you need to do is iterate with nested `for` loops:

```
int two_d_sum(int **arr, int n, int m) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that you can use a flat 2D array, either defined in the scope of `main()` as `int arr[size_n][size_m]` or allocated from the heap as `int (*arr)[size_m] = calloc(sizeof *arr, size_n)` and pass the dimensions first to the function `two_d_sum`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int two_d_sum(size_t n, size_t m, int arr[n][m]) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter the number of arrays in the array (n): ");
    int size_n;
    if (scanf("%d%*c", &size_n) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array in the array (m):");
    int size_m;
    if (scanf("%d%*c", &size_m) != 1)
        return 1;

    // allocate the flat 2D array from the heap
    int (*arr)[size_m] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * size_n);
    // alternately: int (*arr)[size_m] = malloc(sizeof(**arr) * size_n * size_m);
    //          or: int (*arr)[size_m] = malloc(sizeof int[size_n][size_m]);

    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size_n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size_m; j++) {
            int num = 0;
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            if (scanf("%d%*c", &num) != 1)
                return 1;
            arr[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
  
    // ...
    int sum = two_d_sum(size_n, size_m, arr);
    printf("sum is %d\n", sum);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Gerhardh: the `main` functions implements the task described as *a 2D integer array (denoted by double asterisks)*.  Using a 2D VLA or an allocated 2D array seems beyond the OP's skill level at this point, and VLAs might not be available on their programming environment.

Comment: The `int**` arrays are arguably much harder to work with than pointer-to-VLA, since the former tends to be far more error-prone and leaky. The problematic format of them is the very reason why the OP is asking this question in the first place. The only disadvantage with pointer-to-VLA is that the array pointer declarations look a bit exotic until you get the hang of them.

Comment: @Gerhardh: I posted an alternate implementation

Comment: @Lundin: I agree and posted an alternate implementation, but VLAs are alas still optional in C23.

Comment: VLA parameters to functions is not optional in C23. From the C23 draft's definition of `__STDC_NO_VLA__`: "The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support variable length arrays with automatic storage duration. Parameters declared with variable length array types are adjusted and then define objects of automatic storage duration with pointer types. Thus, support for such declarations is mandatory."

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 2D array but an array of pointers forming a look-up table of sorts. Unlike in a 2D array, these pointer tables do not allocate memory in a contiguous chunk. Each time you call `malloc`, a new chunk gets allocated and you can't know where in the heap memory it ends up. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for details.

Your caller code should be replaced with a proper 2D array:

```c
int (*arr) [size_m] = malloc( sizeof(int[size_n][size_m]) );
...
free(arr);
```

You must rewrite the function to use 2D arrays too:

```
int two_d_sum(int n, int m, int arr[n][m])
```

And now it can be called as `two_d_sum(size_n, size_m, arr);`.

And if you like, you can now *probably* do pointer aliasing inside the function like `int* p = (int*)arr;`, although that is still questionable code and strictly speaking still not well-defined still. Because pointer arithmetic going out of bounds on each of the sub arrays in this array-of-arrays is still not well-defined.

I don't see the reason why you can't just access the array as `arr[i][j]` inside the function.

Comment: I find `int* arr = malloc(n*m*sizeof(int));` more intuitive. For accessing an element at the `(i,j)` cell one could define an access method returning  `arr[i*m + j]`. Do you think this method could have some potential drawbacks compared to the one you showcased?

Comment: @MehdiCharife `arr[i*m + j]` is harder to read and therefore easier to get wrong. There may also be various non-obvious performance stuff here, such as what counters this boils down to in the machine code and if that resulting code is suitable for data caching or not. But the main argument is readability, we expect to access a 2D array as `arr[i][j]` and nothing else.