# Accesing to value of 2D array using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers, memory, multidimensional-array

I'm studying multy-pointers and I watched this [video](https://youtu.be/lCDGo7rK3ms?si=JBufmyZSlp-8GdBX), where explains that, if we want to access the value of a 2D array, we use double indirection like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    int** p = &a[0][0];

    printf("%d", **p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But I get a `segmentation fault`. If I do instead a single indirection:

```
    int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    int** p = &a[0][0];

    printf("%d", *p);
```

I get the correct value `a[0][0] = 1`. Now, if I use pointer arithmetic in the single inderection,

```
    printf("%d", *(p+1));
```

I get `a[1][0] = 3`, which makes sense because if I `printf("%d", sizeof(p))`, I get 8 bytes.

Now my question is, How do I get `a[0][1]` and `a[1][1]` using pointer arithmetic?

Comment: [An array of arrays is *not* the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440456/440558).

Comment: Also note that with your definition, the result of `*(p+1)` is a *pointer*. It's *exactly* the same as `p[1]`. If the pointer-to-pointer worked as you expected (which it doesn't, see above) then the correct variant would be `*(*(p + 1))`. On this note, `*p` is the same as `*(p + 0)` which is the same as `p[0]` which is a *pointer* and not a value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand what you said, but then how I can access the address or value of `a[0][1]`?

Comment: Nowhere in that video does it use “double indirection”; there is no `int**` in it. That said, the video is wrong that the name of an array is a pointer to the array or that, if `a` is a two-dimensional array, `*a` or `a[i]` is a pointer to an array.

Comment: You could create a pointer to the array itself: `int (*p)[2] = &a;` Then `p[i][j]` is basically an alias for `a[i][j]`.

Comment: The movie itself is wrong. Computing `&a[0][0] + 3` invokes Undefined Behavior due to pointer arithmetic outside of an array which type is `int[2]`.

Comment: `int** p = &a[0][0];` isn't valid C. You should stop troubleshooting bugs that the compiler has already found and is obliged to point out for you: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int** p = &a[0][0];
```

This is wrong.  The type of `a[0][0]` is `int`; therefore, the type of `&a[0][0]` is `int *`, not `int **`, and that line should be

```
int *p = &a[0][0];
```

So,

```
*p       == a[0][0] == 1
*(p + 1) == a[0][1] == 2
*(p + 2) == a[1][0] == 3
*(p + 3) == a[1][1] == 4
```

Remember that unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, an array expression will "decay" to a pointer expression and the value of the pointer will be the address of the first element of the array:

```
Expression    Type        "Decays" to    Equivalent expression
----------    ----        -----------    -----------------------
         a    int [2][2]    int (*)[2]     &a[0]
        *a    int [2]       int *          a[0]
      a[i]    int [2]       int *          &a[i][0]
     *a[i]    int           n/a            a[i][0]

        &a    int (*)[2][2] n/a            n/a
     &a[i]    int (*)[2]    n/a            n/a
  &a[i][j]    int *         n/a            n/a
```

This is important - a 2D array expression decays to a pointer *to an array*, not a pointer to a pointer.

If

```
a[i] == *(a + i)
```

then

```
a[i][j] == *(*(a + i) + j)
```

So if you declare a pointer

```
int (*p)[2] = a;
```

then

```
 p       == &a[0]                // int (*)[2] == int (*)[2]
*p       ==  a[0]   == &a[0][0]  // int * == int *
*(p + 1) ==  a[1]   == &a[1][0]  // int * == int *

*(*(p + 1)) == a[1][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tip: enable all warnings**

`int** p = &a[0][0];` should have warned.

**Depending on level on indirection**

> How do I get a[0][1] and a[1][1] using pointer arithmetic?

```
// Using different dimensions as it is more illustrative.
#define DIM1 3
#define DIM2 2

int a[DIM1][DIM2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};

int (*q)[DIM1][DIM2] = &a;
printf("%d %d\n", (*q)[0][0],  (*q)[2][1]);
printf("%d %d\n", q[0][0][0],  q[0][2][1]);

int (*r)[DIM2] = a;
printf("%d %d\n", r[0][0],  r[2][1]);

int *ta = a[0];
int *tb = a[2];
printf("%d %d\n", ta[0],  tb[1]);

int ua = a[0][0];
int ub = a[2][1];
printf("%d %d\n", ua, ub);
```

All print `1 6`

Comment: A conforming compiler _must_ give a warning or other message in this case. More likely the OP just ignored the warning which was given.