# Passing array of strings to function in C: `str[dim1][str_size]` vs `*str[dim1]`

Tags: arrays, c, string

I have a function that takes an array of strings as argument, like this one:

```c
void print_string_array(int *dims, const char **str) {
  for (int i=0; i<dims[0]; i++) {
    printf("STRING %d: %s\n", i, str[i]);
  }
}
```

I'd like to understand why using it with (showing without the `free` calls):

```c
int main() {
     char *test_str_1[3];
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      test_str_1[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4096);
      test_str_1[i][0] = '\0';
     }
     strncat(test_str_1[0], "This is first line", 4095);
     strncat(test_str_1[1], "This is second line", 4095);
     strncat(test_str_1[2], "This is third line", 4095);

     int dims[1] = {3};
     print_string_array(dims, (const char **) test_str_1);
     return 0;
}
```

works fine, but the following segfaults at the `printf` line in `print_string_array`:

```c
int main () {
     char test_str_1[3][4096];
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      test_str_1[i][0] = '\0';
     }
     strncat(test_str_1[0], "This is first line", 4095);
     strncat(test_str_1[1], "This is second line", 4095);
     strncat(test_str_1[2], "This is third line", 4095);

     int dims[1] = {3};
     print_string_array(dims, (const char **) test_str_1);
     return 0;
}
```

I thought the two would be equivalent, but obviously this is not the case...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Why do you pass a pointer to a single integer value?

Comment: As for your problem, [an array of arrays is ***not*** the same as a pointer to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440205/casting-void-to-2d-array-of-int-c/18440456#18440456). That you feel the need to do an explicit conversion (cast) should have been an indicator that you're probably are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: the actual use case can have mutliple dimensions, and I have another `int rank` argument for the rank of the array. I am writing some wrappers around HDF5 functions.  And thanks a lot for the link ! That actually clarifies things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are completely different.

1. `test_str_1[3][4096]` is an array of `char`
2. `char *test_str_1[3]` is an array of pointers to `char`

```
void print_string_array(int *dims, const char **str)
```

requires pointer to pointer to char and it will work with an array from point 2. as it will decay to pointer to pointer.

To use the char array you need to declare function as:

```
void print_string_array(int *dims, const char (*str)[4096])
```

The array from point 1. will decay to pointer to array of 4096 `char` elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main () {
     char test_str_1[3][4096];
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      test_str_1[i][0] = '\0';
     }
     printf("%p\n",&test_str_1);
     printf("%p\n",test_str_1);
     printf("%p\n",test_str_1[0]);
     printf("%p\n",test_str_1[1]);
     printf("%p\n",test_str_1[2]);

     strncat(test_str_1[0], "This is first line", 4095);
     strncat(test_str_1[1], "This is second line", 4095);
     strncat(test_str_1[2], "This is third line", 4095);

     int dims[1] = {3};
     print_string_array(dims, (const char **) test_str_1);
     return 0;
}
```

Try it with this, it'll tell the reason.

Comment: cast does not change anything. It only **silences** warnings.

Comment: I am not the one who added that, wdym?